# Where am I supposed to post a question regarding hardware?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding RAM compatibility and hardware.

Can someone please let me know where to post this question?

Answer (score 8):

**[SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)**

Its [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

Answer (score 6):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is the right site, as long as the question is not about:

- videogames or **consoles**
- websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
- **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer**
- issues specific to corporate IT support and networks
- **a shopping or buying recommendation**

You can ask questions about software and hardware on *Super User*, if they respect those restrictions.